# connecting to kernel jupyter notebook and using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, package, kernel

I realize questions similar to mine have been put out here. However, I haven't found a good answer to the problem I'm having. I've been using jupyter notebook along with r for about 2 weeks and it has been working fine. Up until this morning, that is.
I am all of a sudden unable to connect to the jupyter notebook through the irkernel. When I attempt to open any notebook with r using the r environment I have set up in anaconda, it will open, and then proceed to become stuck on "connecting to kernel". It then ends up saying that I can't connect to the kernel. This happens both with me at home and at school so I don't think it is a network issue, and the rest of my internet works fine.

I have checked whether my computer is registering the existence of my kernels in my command line, and it is (see below):

```
(base) ashleyschumann Mon Mar 02 ~$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  ir         /Users/ashleyschumann/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  python3    /Users/ashleyschumann/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
(base) ashleyschumann Mon Mar 02 ~$
```

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling r and updating all of my packages, which has not fixed anything.

So I was able to get everything fixed finally after uninstalling and reinstalling everything (which took forever but that's okay). Now I'm just having an issue where I can't load ggplot2 in jupyter notebok because it is saying the rlang package is too old of a version. When I try to update the package, I get this error message:

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
     namespace ‘rlang’ 0.2.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.0 is required
    Traceback:
    1. library(ggplot2)
    2. tryCatch({
     .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
     .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
     .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)
     . }, error = function(e) {
     .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
     .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
     .     else ""
     .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
     .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
     .     if (logical.return) 
     .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
     .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
     . })
    3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
    4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
    5. value[[3L]](cond)
    6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

What is a good way to force the rlang package to update?

Comment: What command are you using to launch your notebooks? Is `jupyter notebook` running somewhere for the notebooks to connect to?

Comment: So I was able to get everything fixed finally after uninstalling and reinstalling everything (which took forever but that's okay). Now I'm just having an issue where I can't load ggplot2 in jupyter notebok because it is saying the rlang package is too old of a version.